# How to rename Webdav folder in another

Tags: linux, apache, mod-rewrite, webdav

In my server with apache and mod_dav have the following webdav rules in config

```
Alias /admin_folder /var/www/test_site_cloud/web/admin_folder/files
```

so I have /admin_folder mount.
Now I need to rename another folder inside this Alias

/admin_folder/foo/bar into /admin_folder/foo/new_name_folder

There is some method??
I try with mod_rewrite but in my webdav client don't work....

```
RewriteEngine on
rewriterule ^admin_folder/foo/bar(.*)$  admin_folder/foo/new_name_folder$1 [r=301,nc]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not going to work because the webdav module is not aware of how things were rewritten. You might be able to do it with a symlink, if mod_dav follows those, otherwise you are out of luck.